# .NET Core 3.1 EntityFramework Core DatabaseModel Getting No Argument given

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When using .NET Core 2.2. I could do the below
test.cs:

```
var context = new DatabaseModels();
Test = conext.Test.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a => a.ID);
```

However, when I upgraded to .NET Core 3.1. I had the add the following lines to my DBContext file in order for the code to run.

DbContext.cs:

```
public class DatabaseModels: DbContext

{
        public DatabaseModels(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    { }
public DbSet<Test> Test {get; set;}
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=<removed>;Initial Catalog=<removed>;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
        }
     }


}
```

startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseModels>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configurationSection.Value));
```

However, now this causes an error for all my var context = new DatabaseModels(); giving me an error of
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'DatabaseModels.DatabaseModels(DBContextOptions)'

I tried adding null but this stated it can not be null. I tried other options as well and no go. What overload do I put in var context = new DatabaseModels(); to make it not error?

Error:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'DatabaseModels.DatabaseModels(DbContextOptions)'

Comment: Assuming that your DatabaseModels is your context, is that class inheriting from "DbContext"?  e.g. "public class DatabaseModels : DbContext"

Comment: Correct. public class DatabaseModels: DbContext. 

public DatabaseModels(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    { }

is included in that public class.

Comment: Where are you trying to new up this context?  And why not use dependency injection, as is typical for .Net Core 3.1 projects?  Instead of "var context = new..." why not inject the context where you need it?  I assume you have a "services.AddDbContext()" call in your Startup.cs?

Comment: Do you have services.AddDbContext... in your startup file?Pls show it for us.

Comment: Bryan. I do    var context = new DatabaseModels(); so i can populate the list Test (Test = conext.Test.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(a => a.ID);).  However, since I had to (public DatabaseModels(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    { }) I am getting that var context = new DatabaseModels(); needs to have an option (overload).  

Looking to be able to in other files load lists from DatabaseModels. In .NET Core 2.2 I didn't need to use an option/overload. However, for the life of me I can't figure out what to put in the overload to get it to work.

Comment: I think your context class is fine, but adding the relevant AddDbContext() section from your Startup and a more complete example of how you are trying to use the context will help us help you.  If you are using this in a controller or service class, post that part of the code.  Just a line or two doesn't provide enough context (no pun intended).

Comment: Sergey. Yes.  services.AddDbContext<DatabaseModels>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configurationSection.Value)); is in the startup.cs. However, with 2.2 I didn't need to have  public DatabaseModels(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    { } in my DBConext class. With it added. Every time I try updating the var context = new DatabaseModels(); value, the error I mentioned above happens.

Comment: Michael, add the additional code to your original post (edit your question).  It's very hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Bryan - I added the missing code to the original post

Comment: Thanks, but what would really help is at least one example of where you are using the context.  Where you have "var context = new DatabaseModels(); "   Typically, in .Net Core 3.1 the recommendation is to use dependency injection to get an instance of your DbContext, not to "new" up a concrete object.  If I can see an example, I can help you mod the code to use DI.  If you are using this code in a Controller or Service class, it's easy to just inject the context and use that (removing the "new")

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code if you dont want to use net core services:

```
var conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnectionString"];
var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseModels>();
dbContextOptions.UseSqlServer(conString);
var context = new DatabaseModels(dbContextOptions.Options);
```

Comment: I had to slightly modify this code to `new DatabaseModels(dbContextOptions.Options)` because dbContextOptions is still the builder, can't just pass that directly. Had to use the `.Options`

Comment: @deherch Thank you for a feedback , I really appreciate it  and fixed my answer.